# Show that there is an injective homomorphism between $Aut(S_3)$ and $Bij(\{(12), (1 3), (2 3)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-homomorphism

Let $X$ be equal to $\{(1 2), (1 3), (2 3)\}$. How can I prove the existence of an injective homomorphism between $Aut(S_3)$ and $Bij(X)$ ?

I was thinking about this :

Let $\varphi$ be a map between $Aut(S_3)$ and $Bij(X)$ defined as following :

For $\psi$ in $Aut(S_3)$,  $\varphi(\psi) = f$ with $f : X \longrightarrow X$ such as $\forall x \in X$, $f(x) = \psi(x)$

Then I think I can show that $\varphi$ is an injective homomorphism.

Do you think it's correct ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What's the group operation on $X$?

Comment: José Carlos Santos : The group operation is map composition

Comment: Surely the bijections of a set of three elements consists of the permutations of these three elements? [Many define a "permutation" in exactly this way.]

Comment: ancientmathematician : yes I agree

Comment: Then which element of $X$ is the identity element?

Comment: José Carlos Santos : X is defined as a set, not a group, so I believe it doesn't necessarily have to contain the identity element.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $X$ is not a group, but $Bij(X)$ is a group for the composition law.

Comment: @Laury Your definition is the correct one, except that it should be $f(x)=\psi(x)$ (and not $\varphi(x)$). Then, what you have to prove is that if an automorphism of $S_3$ keeps all the transposition fixed, then it keeps all the elements fixed (so it is the identity). Do you see what could let you conclude that ?

Comment: @Laury Right. My mistake.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes sorry you're right it was supposed to be $f(x) = \psi(x)$. As the transpositions generate $S_3$, I can indeed conclude that if an automorphism of $S_3$ keeps all the transposition fixed then it keeps all the elements fixed. So I can conclude that the map is injective, right ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Even if an automorphism of S_3 fixes the transpositions and the 3-cycles; we can find a map from S_3 to S_3 for example f , f(12) =(13), f(13)= (12) , f(23)=(23) ; it is an automorphism but it's not identity

Comment: @Laury Yes, you got it !

Comment: @chloe2107 I don't understand your point. An automorphism in the kernel of the defined map is an automorphism which fixes all the transposition. What one has to show is that this automorphism is the identity. The example you give does not fix the transposition, so its image by the map is not $Id_{X}$...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yeah okay, my bad, I wasn't talking about the same thing

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you very much !